# Probability of four grandchildren in a famil

Tags: probability

Lets say that families always have one, two, or three children, with probability 1/4, 1/2, and
1/4 respectively. Assume that eventually everyone gets married and has children, what
is the probability of a couple having exactly four grandchildren?

**My approach:-**

I tried to make a tree kind of structure

So in the first generation I would have cases of 1 kid , 2 kids or 3 kids (represented below as 1, 2, 3)

**1**  (case when couple initially had 1 kid)

11,12,13  (11 represents the event that the first kid has 1 child in the second generation)

**2** (case when couple had 2 kids initially, named them as 2a,2b)

2a1,2a2,2a3,2b1,2b2,2b3 (since there are 2 kids so I made further 3 cases for both 2a and 2b)

**3** (the case when couple had 3 kids in first generations , named them as 3a,3b,3c)

3a1,3a2,3a3,3b1,3b2,3b3,3c1,3c2,3c3 (now these 3a,3b,3c can have further 1,2,3 kids as shown)

I am not able to proceed further, how will I make my sample space and find the result further.

Comment: It's just a matter of writing out all the cases.  Tedious, but hardly difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way one can have $4$ grandchildren is to first have $2$ or $3$ children, as a single child can lead to maximum of $3$ grandchildren. The possibilities of $4$ grandchildren are -

$i$) From $2$ children

a) one of the children has $1$ child and the other has $3$ children
b) Both children have $2$ children each

So, $P (4 ~\text{GC}|2 \text{C}) = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

$ii$) From $3$ children

Two of them must have one child each and the third should have two children.

So, $P (4 ~\text{GC}|3 \text{C}) = 3 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

Now, $P (4 ~\text{GC}) = P (4 ~\text{GC}|2 \text{C}) \cdot P(2 \text{C}) + P (4 ~\text{GC}|3 \text{C}) \cdot P(3 \text{C})$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is the probability P(2C) of 2 children  (lets say them being X and Y) given as 1/2 equally distributed between these two i.e. will X and Y both have 1/4 probability ? won't we need the probability individually of X and Y individually to compute the answer ?

Similarly in the case of P(3C) , how is the probability divided among these 3 children , will each of the 3 have probability of 1/9

Comment: $P(2C) = 1/2$ and $P(3C) = 1/4$ are given in the question and that is what you need to use.

Comment: @Fin27 Take $3C$ case for example. $P(3C)$ is simply the probability that someone would have $3$ children. It has nothing to do with who those $3$ children are. But when you try to find $P(4GC|3C)$, any of the three children could have $2$ children and others $1$ each and that is why you multiply by $3$.